# How to troubleshoot jack detection in Pulseaudio

Tags: audio, alsa, pulseaudio

Pulseaudio apparently supports "jack detection", meaning auto-detection of whether anything is plugged into each jack (e.g., headphone jack, line out jack) or not.

Unfortunately, Pulseaudio's jack detection isn't working for me.  How do I troubleshoot it?  What steps should I follow to narrow down the cause of the problem?

---

I've found [this guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/PreciseJackDetectionTesting) from Ubuntu.  It taught me to compare the output of `amixer -c0 contents` when something is plugged into the jack, vs when nothing is plugged in; and to do the same for `pacmd list-cards`.

In my case, I found that jack detection seems to be working at the ALSA / kernel level.  `amixer -c0 contents` outputs the following when nothing is plugged in:

```
numid=41,iface=CARD,name='Line Out CLFE Jack'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=off
```

When something is plugged in, the last line changes to `values=on`.  This seems to indicate that jack detection is working at the ALSA / kernel level.

However, jack detection doesn't seem to be working at the Pulseaudio level.  The output from `pacmd list-cards` is the same whether something is plugged in or not.  In particular, I see something like

```
    ports:
            ...
            analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                    properties:
            ...
```

regardless of whether anything is plugged in or not.  This makes me suspect that maybe Pulseaudio is at fault here.

What are the next steps to troubleshoot this?

---

If it's relevant, here is my information about my particular system.  I am using Fedora 21.  Here are some package version numbers: `kernel-3.17.7-300.fc21.x86_64`, `pulseaudio-5.0-25.fc21.x86_64`, `alsa-plugins-pulseaudio-1.0.28-3.fc21.x86_64`, `alsa-lib-1.0.28-2.fc21.x86_64`.  Here's the sound controller that shows up in `lspci -vvnn`:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Biostar Microtech Int'l Corp Device [1565:8228]
```

Here are the first few lines from `/proc/asound/card0/codec#2` (there is no `codec#0` or `coded#1` on my machine, though that would normally be the first place to check; `codec#3` is for HDMI and doesn't seem relevant):

```
Codec: Realtek ALC892
Address: 2
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x10ec0892
Subsystem Id: 0x15658228
Revision Id: 0x100302
```

That's information about my particular machine.  But maybe a general answer that is generically applicable will be more useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

Solved un-commenting this line on

> /etc/pulse/default.pa

```
load-module module-switch-on-port-available
```

Manually it can be done

```
pacmd load-module module-switch-on-port-available
```

Tested on a netrunner 17 / ubuntu 15.10